# confused about the output of hist

Tags: matlab, histogram

I am confused by the

```
[m,n]=hist(y,x)
```

such as

```
M = [1, 2, 3;
     4, 5, 6;
     1, 2, 3];

[m,n] =  hist(M,1:3)
```

Which results in

```
 m = 2     0     0
     0     2     0
     1     1     3
```

Can someone please explain how `m` is calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hist` actually takes vectors as input arguments, you wrote a matrix, so it just handles your input as if it was several vector-inputs. The output are the number of elements for each container (in your case `1:3`, the second argument).

```
[m,n] =  hist([1,2,3;4,5,6;1,2,3],1:3)
```

treats each column as one input. You put in 3 inputs (# of columns) and you get 3 outputs.

```
[2 0 1]'
```

means, for the input `[1;4;1]` and the bin `1:3` two elements are in *bin* 1 and one element is in *bin* 3.

Look at the last column of `m`, here all three values are in the third bin, which makes sense, since the corresponding vector is `[3;6;3]`, and out of those numbers all have to go into the *bin/container 3*.

Comment: Please tell me what's the meaning of "bin 3"?

Comment: The second argument in `hist` are the *bin's*, or *containers* where you want to sort your values. When writing `1:3` you want all values in the first argument to be placed in either, 1, 2 or 3. *bin 3* mean the third number, i.e. 3. If you are still confused, please read http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html?searchHighlight=hist

Comment: If the answer helped you (which it did) please don't forget to accept the answer @CCIEGZM. Thanks!